# Java Hibernate MYSQL MatchMode Exact

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, string-matching

i am using hibernate with MYSQL.i have a question about Hibernate MatchMode.EXACT here is my code.

```
    final org.hibernate.Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Projection p = Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"),"id").add(Projections.property("name"),"name");
    Criteria criteria =  session.createCriteria(Student.class).setProjection(p).add(Restrictions.ilike("name","richie",MatchMode.EXACT)).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Student.class));
    ArrayList<Student>students= new ArrayList<Student>(criteria.list());
    for(Student student:students)System.out.println(student.getId()+" "+student.getName());
```

when using START,END,ANYWHERE is working OK my question is why EXACT don't match?

in this case i am querying by richie and exists a richie in DB.

i was wondering if like[EXACT] MUST be a Regex?

if it is why this is not returning any result?
mySQL query.

```
select this_.ID as y0_, this_.name as y1_ from student this_ where lower(this_.name) like '[a-z]'
```

Comment: oooops my fault i was checking in a deeper way and i have found in the DB is 'richie ' with a empty space in the end.. but still like [a-z] not working?? why?

Comment: There no Regex in HQL and Restrictions.ilike. `like '[a-z]'` will search for '[a-z]' as string, not as Regex